# Problem when plotted a model in Keras using IPython.display and model_to_dot

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Good morning, friends

Please see my screenshots links, when I plotted a CNN model in Keras with: `SVG(model_to_dot(happyModel).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))`, the layout was too **large** thus some parts were **cropped**. I use Jupyter, how can I solve it without using other plotting methods? Thank you!

[Pic1: the plotted model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iysiB.jpg)

[Pic2: what I import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAygq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the class `IPython.display.Image` with the parameter `unconfined=True`.